# Is there a Cordova storage option without requiring WebView?

Tags: cordova

It would appear that all the Cordova options for storage (e.g., localStorage, WebSQL, IndexedDB) require using WebView. However, I do not want to use WebView. Do I have any options?

Comment: cordova code runs inside a webview, so what do you expect? There are plugins for storing into NSUserDefaults or android preferences, or you can use file plugin to store files

Comment: Um, no, Cordova code does not have to run inside a WebView. My current application is proof.

Comment: So, how do you use cordova? How do you create your UI? Why do you use cordova if you don't use the webview?

Comment: I use HTML/CSS/JS to create the UI, but it does not use a WebView, which is a specific Android component that lets you view webpages. My app is NOT a web application, per se.

Comment: Dude, cordova uses the webview component internally to load local resources, you are using the webview already

Comment: Yes, but my UI doesn't, and that's the key point. The most important point!

Comment: If you use cordova and HTML/CSS/JS to create the UI, you are using a webview. The only way I know to use cordova and not use the webview is using reactJS, but reactJS doesn't use HTML for the UI

Comment: Okay, let's put it this way... Here's the guide for how to use Android WebViews: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/webview.html. I don't do this and I certainly don't want to. It's too complicated and unnecessary for my application. (For the record, my application is essentially complete. I'm just waiting for a storage solution; hence, my question.)

Comment: that is for using the cordova webview inside a native application, so some parts/screens are native and some parts are displayed on the webview (all the HTML/CSS/JS). A regular cordova aplication already uses the cordova webview, it's all a webview where you run your code, so you can use any webview storage

Comment: https://iphonedevlog.wordpress.com/explanation-of-phonegapcordova-for-the-layman/

Answer (score 1):

Use the file plugin, it does not use the browser to perform file access.  It uses native libraries on ios/Android/etc... to manage the file system.

Comment: Okay, I was wrong. LocalStorage *does* work. My testing had a bug.